# Syntax error for multiple change column in alter table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to alter a table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE book 
    ADD COLUMN `ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER `id`,
    CHANGE COLUMN `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CHANGE COLUMN `author_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL;
```

But it keeps giving this syntax error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, CHANGE COLUMN `author_id` bigint un' at line 3
```

I have no idea where I'm going wrong here. The SQL seems quite all right to me and each of the table alteration can be successfully executed individually:

```
ALTER TABLE book ADD COLUMN `ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER `id`;
ALTER TABLE book CHANGE COLUMN `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE book CHANGE COLUMN `author_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL;
```

I can use the individual versions but there are quite some large tables that I need to alter so it would be better if I use a combined query which should be faster.

Why doesn't the combined SQL work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your below code line cause per syntax in documentation `CHANGE` expects a new column name like `CHANGE [COLUMN] old_col_name new_col_name column_definition`

```
CHANGE COLUMN `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

So you can either change this to

```
CHANGE COLUMN `id` `new_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

(OR) consider using `MODIFY` rather like `MODIFY [COLUMN] col_name column_definition`

```
MODIFY [COLUMN] `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Comment: "This is a MySQL extension to standard SQL, which permits only one of each clause per ALTER TABLE statement. For example, to drop multiple columns in a single statement, do this:" -- This seems like the answer? Only 1 type of column change can be in a single alter table query?

Comment: @kavoir.com, Yes, only one addition/change/drop per alter table statement and can't be combined. Check the syntax properly and you will see that.

Comment: @kavoir.com, see edit in answer for better clarification.

Comment: This is really weird. I tried this and it worked! -- `ALTER TABLE sub_subject
 ADD `ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER `id`,
 MODIFY `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 CHANGE `subject` `subject_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL;`

Comment: @kavoir.com, I must have answered with a sleeping eye ... please see edit in answer if it helps.